# how to use libPusher library in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to implement the chat application in my project using libPusher library in ios. I don't have any idea for the Pusher. So, any one can help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Too huge question, go and read some tutorial.....

Comment: Give some tutorial link's

Comment: @sarosar You've chosen the library, it is your job to look for documentation, it is sufficiently described [at the GitHub](https://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher).

Comment: @sarosar, answered, have a look, and go through all stuff, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following tutorial. Its comprehensively defined here.

https://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher

Go through it, implement delegates. An over-view I am writing here.

Choose names, This you have to mention on your server, ask help of some sever guy around you.

```
_privateChannelName = channelName; //Mention on server
self.messageFieldName = fieldName; //Mention on server.
```

_client = [PTPusher pusherWithKey:kPusherKey delegate:self encrypted:YES];
    _client.reconnectDelay = 3.0;

```
_client.authorizationURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kPusherClientAuthorizationURL]; //You have to create authentication also.

[_client connect];
```

You have to put delegate methods, below

```
- (void)subscribeToPrivateChannel:(NSString *)channelName withFieldName:(NSString *)messagefieldName;
- (void)pusher:(PTPusher *)pusher connectionDidConnect:(PTPusherConnection *)connection;
- (void)pusher:(PTPusher *)pusher connection:(PTPusherConnection *)connection failedWithError:(NSError *)error;
- (void)pusher:(PTPusher *)pusher connection:(PTPusherConnection *)connection didDisconnectWithError:(NSError *)error willAttemptReconnect:(BOOL)reconnect;
- (BOOL)pusher:(PTPusher *)pusher connectionWillConnect:(PTPusherConnection *)connection;
- (BOOL)pusher:(PTPusher *)pusher connectionWillAutomaticallyReconnect:(PTPusherConnection *)connection afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;
- (void)pusher:(PTPusher *)pusher didSubscribeToChannel:(PTPusherChannel *)channel;
- (void)pusher:(PTPusher *)pusher didUnsubscribeFromChannel:(PTPusherChannel *)channel;
- (void)pusher:(PTPusher *)pusher didFailToSubscribeToChannel:(PTPusherChannel *)channel withError:(NSError *)error;
- (void)pusher:(PTPusher *)pusher willAuthorizeChannel:(PTPusherChannel *)channel withRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request;
- (void)pusher:(PTPusher *)pusher didReceiveErrorEvent:(PTPusherErrorEvent *)errorEvent;
```

Kindly read them, go through all stuff, and come back with some existing struggle, and questions.

Happy Coding.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks V S for your answer

Comment: Accept if it helps :)